# STM32f4 401cDisco: When I use can StdPeriph it shows lots of errors in it's basic functions

Tags: arm, stm32, can-bus

When I attach my own libraries (that have already worked on other devices) `stm32f4xx_can.c` goes crazy as shown in this photo:

[image: Screenshot]

Eclipse says it has something to do with these colons and semicolons, but that's apparently not the problem.

How do I handle this? What's the reason?

Comment: Try running indexer again: rightclick project -> index -> rebuild.
These errors are not compilation errors but just analysis done by Eclipse, which may not reflect actual problems. What matters is what you get during compilation.

Comment: It doesn't work, nothing changed :(

Comment: Does the project compile? If not, what are the errors given by the compiler ("Console" tab, not "Errors" tab)?

Comment: It builds but does not create binary file. Instead i found this "makefile", "objects.list", "objects.mk" and "sources.mk". 

It's an example from console:
"C:/Users/Piotr/workspace/xcan/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/stm32f4xx_can.h:627:39: note: in expansion of macro 'CANx'
 ITStatus CAN_GetITStatus(CAN_TypeDef* CANx, uint32_t CAN_IT);
    
In file included from ../src/main.c:2:0:
C:/Users/Piotr/workspace/xcan/StdPeriph_Driver/inc/stm32f4xx_can.h:627:45: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'uint32_t'
 ITStatus CAN_GetITStatus(CAN_TypeDef* CANx, uint32_t CAN_IT);
"

Comment: Entire console is, like, kilometer long. Additional thing i cannot understand is error in CMSIS-> device-> stm32f4xx.h:
"#define PERIPH_BASE           ((uint32_t)0x40000000) /*!< Peripheral base address in the alias region"

Comment: Can you paste it all to pastebin or something similar? Those errors indicate some general problem with your project. For example, maybe you're missing the global MCU type definition, such as "STM32F40_41xxx".

Comment: I couldn't test it yet, but when I pasted code to new libraries instead of manually adding the files, program allowed me to build it without any errors and create bin. I have no idea what has just happened.

Comment: By "new libraries" do you mean STM32Cube? From the screenshot I can see you're trying to use Standard Peripheral drivers, which is not what Eclipse adds to a template project when a new project is created. If that's what you mean by "manually adding files", then there's more you have to do than just moving files.